# How to express "Today I would like to talk about X" when opening a speech

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

Can one use 「本日、Xを話したいです」　when opening a speech, or is it too rough? For example, translations for the sentence "Today I would like to talk about my past" that I can think of are 「本日、私の過去を話したいです」　or 「本日、私の過去について話したいです」　or　「本日、私の過去について話したいと思います」。 Which of these would be the best, or is there anything better?

Answer (score 9):

I think you can say...

> 本日は(or今日は)、XXについて[話]{はな}したいと思います。

or

> 本日は、XXについてお[話]{はな}ししたいと思います。(to sound more formal)

Comment: Thank you! I have seen 「と思います」　added to the end before, but it means "I think", so it doesn't seem to make grammatical sense. Why is this added to the end, rather than ending with 「話したいです」？

Comment: @miikaelf We often say ...したいと思います / ...しようと思います in a rather formal situation. I think it sounds a bit more polite and less direct than したいです. Probably したいと思います/させていただきます is like "I would like to..." and したいです is like "I want to..."